# Multiple buttons with same properties

Tags: selenium

I have 2 buttons with same type, class and value. How can I click on the second button? Can anyone help me with the xpath? The code is like this

I want to select the first one. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to click on the element with innerHTML/text as **'Ansök om lån'**, that is the first element.

Below is the java code for clicking on first element, as mentioned above:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Ansök om lån']")).click();
```

Similarly for clicking the second element, you can use the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Jämför sparkonton']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Subh its worked . And this one also worked for me driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Ansök om lån')]")).click();

Comment: I'm looking for a similar thing But in my case, the text is also same for multiple buttons and instead of anchor tag, I have submit button. Any idea how to get the xpath of just the first button?

Comment: @SanchitKhera : You can wrap your xpath with parenthesis and use squared brackets with the number inside it denoting the position of the element in DOM. In your case xpath might be like this : *(xpath of submit button)[1]* for the first button, *(xpath of submit button)[2]* for the second button.. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

Use array notation to get first or second element.